# How can I force a Phonegap app to maintain the same proportions regardless of screen size?

Tags: html, css, cordova, responsive-design

I'm writing my first Phonegap app, and I'm having a bit of a headache dealing with all the different screen sizes. So, since my app is aimed only at phones I think I know how my ideal solution would **work**, but I'm just totally clueless as to how I would implement it.

Basically, I want the entire page to behave like an image. Rather than staying the same size and wrapping into new lines as the screen gets smaller, I want the actual font size of the text to decrease, maintaining all the spacing and proportions of the design. I've tried using only percentages to define margins, widths, font sizes, etc., but it hasn't worked exactly as I'd like.

Comment: Why don't you start with using a ui framework for you phone gap app like jquery mobile or bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something like image that will shrink/decrease the fontsize, spacing, and proportions of design, you have to write media queries accordingly.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 550px) {
    .title {
        font-size:11px
    }
    .body-box {
        width:440px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .title {
        font-size:12px
    }
    .body-box {
        width:480px;
    }

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 650px) {
    .title {
        font-size:13px
    }
    .body-box {
        width:520px;
    }
}
```

This also has some drawbacks. For very small-screen displays or low-resolution displays(around 350px), if you keep this ratio, it will be about 7px and that size is too small to read. If anyone sees on QHD tab (2160px), the font size will be 44px which will be very large.

The long term and perfect solutions to an app like yours will be to start a responsive design.

You can start designing your HTML app layout using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/). It's responsive and mobile first, and it will maintain the layout.

Otherwise you can use [onsen.io](https://onsen.io/) framework, which is also a responsive HTML5 framework for Cordova and Phonegap.